# About the verb "To attend"

Tags: grammar, verbs, vocabulary

I have received an email from my boss to attend a course, can I reply to her email by this sentence:

```
Thank you for your email,
I will attend. 
Best regards.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reply implies but does not explicitly refer to an object. What will you attend?

“Please attend the course.” “I will attend.” is a structured conversation. If you include the original email in your reply, it is clear that you are referring to “course” as the object in your own sentence. The parallel use of *attend* in the two sentences strengthens the implication of your unwritten object.

“I will attend.” If you send your reply without the original, the object is unclear, and your sentence is incomplete, giving at least a feeling of carelessness, or even of sullen acquiescence.

Comment: "I'll be pleased to attend" would sound more polite, and also less like the response of an automaton. (Even if you will not be!)

Comment: @WS2 Agreed - Good etiquette!